# Why doesn't array.splice() work when the array has only 1 element?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce

Is this intended behavior?  I would expect an empty array to be returned here.

JavaScript

```js
let arr = [1];
console.log(arr.splice(0, 1))
```

Console

```
1
```

Comment: It returns `1`, which is a proper result.

Comment: But if I am starting at index 0, and removing 1 item then why would it not return an empty array?

Comment: Because `splice()` returns the value which was 'spliced/cut/removed' from the original array. Try `console.log(arr)` and you will see that it's empty.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Because it returns what was removed, which is [1] in your case. `arr` will be empty after the call.

See example:

```js
let arr = [1];
arr.splice(0, 1);
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: ohh I thought it returned the modified array

Answer (score 3):

[Array.prototype.splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) returns an array of the deleted elements.

Your are logging the returned value of the operation not the current state of the array.

Answer (score 2):

> The splice() method changes the contents of an array by removing
>   existing elements and/or adding new elements.
>   [Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

The syntax of this method is:

```
array.splice(start)
array.splice(start, deleteCount)
array.splice(start, deleteCount, item1, item2, ...)
```

You are using the second syntax and passing `0` as start and `1` as `deleteCount` that means you would like to start at 0th index and delete 1 item (not 1 as value in array).

This method returns an array containing the deleted elements. If only one element is removed, an array of one element is returned. If no elements are removed, an empty array is returned.

So, in this case the result is `[1]` i.e. an array with value of `1` that is the item you just deleted.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this question when I was trying to achieve a function in mini-program. A solution is to check the array's length before using the function `splice`. For example:

```js
if(imgList.length > 1){
    imgList.splice(index, 1);
else{
    imgList = []
}
```

You can try to solve it like that.